# Is there a way to prevent saved authentication in Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, authentication, tortoisesvn, settings

I am using Tortoise SVN, and I tend to have my own username/password stored in it's saved data so that I don't have to authenticate each time.

Trouble is, we have a number of scripts, Final Builder projects and things that use another username - and so this overwrites my own username in the saved data.

Then I go to make a commit and find that it has done it using the other username.

I know that I can manually clear the saved state, but half of the time I forget. I don't mind authenticating each time if necessary, so is there a way to prevent Tortoise SVN from caching at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can turn off authentication caching in the subversion config files, which you can usually find in `%appdata%\Subversion\config`.

Look at the `store-passwords` and `store-auth-creds` settings there.

BTW: [AnkhSVN](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) users can find a dialog to delete only specific credentials in
Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Subversion Environment -> Authentication Cache

Comment: Nice! I missed the conf file option.

Comment: My Tortoise (1.6.11.20210) ignores both those settings and stores passwords any way.

Comment: This file doesn't appear to exist any more (v1.8.7)

Comment: @Liam In TortoiseSVN v1.9.4, the `store-passwords` and `store-auth-creds` settings are configured in the `%appdata%\Subversion\servers` file instead.  They added a comment block in the `%appdata%\Subversion\config` file indicating the move.

Answer (score 7):

TortoiseSVN 1.9.3, Build 27038 - 64 Bit.

TortoiseSVN->Settings->Advanced:
**Option "AllowAuthSave" value change to "false"**

[image: preview Settings]

Comment: To clarify, this *disables* the checkbox, whereas the `config` file affects whether or not it is checked by default.

Answer (score 6):

From TortoiseSVN's help:

> Some people like to have the authentication data deleted when they log off Windows, or on shutdown. The way to do that is to use a shutdown script to delete the `%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth` directory, e.g.

```
@echo off
rmdir /s /q "%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth"
```

> You can find a description of how to install such scripts at windows-help-central.com .

Maybe the scripts, Final Builder projects etc. should clean the authentication data after they run.

Those scripts and tools probably use `svn` and not TortoiseSVN. In that case, [the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch09.html#svn-ch-9-sect-1.1) lists this handy switch:

> `--no-auth-cache`
>
> Prevents caching of authentication information (e.g. username and password) in the Subversion administrative directories.

Comment: You can avoid the hassle of running a dos command at shutdown by simply putting an entry in the windows Startup folder.  This is probably slightly less safe, but super easy.

Answer (score 3):

TortoiseSVN store the credentials in Subversion's default directory: `%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth` in three subdirectories:

- svn.simple contains credentials for basic authentication (username/password).
- svn.ssl.server contains SSL server certificates.
- svn.username contains credentials for username-only authentication

You might have a build event that can modify or move these files.

More details: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug.html#tsvn-dug-general-auth

Comment: the other answers appear to be out of date, there isn't a conf file any more (v1.8.7) This is the current correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off authentication caching in the subversion config files, which you can usually find in %appdata%\Subversion\config.

Look at the store-passwords and store-auth-creds settings there.

BTW: AnkhSVN users can find a dialog to delete only specific credentials in Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Subversion Environment -> Authentication Cache

My question is what if I want to apply this changes at the server level. I try making this changes to the Server.config file but it does not seems to work properly is there another way I can accomplish this?